How to fix the wrong pathing in Node.js?
I'm currently learning about APIs, and when I use Postman to post the login, it tells me 'message': 'Internal server error'. I traced the issue and found the error related to the pathing. Here is my directory structure:
this is my src structure

content in test.js file:
import '../controllers/userController.js';
when I'm at routes/ and use node test.js it gives me the error:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module xxx/src/controllers/models/userModels.js imported from xxx/src/controllers/userController.js
How can I fix this error? As you can see, the error indicates controllers/models/userModels.js, but the real code is trying to find controllers/userController.js.
I've tried changing 'test.js' to import ../controllers/userController.js, and it's working fine now.
so, I also suspect that it may be because of the structure of the mobaXterm program?

